# How to write values from numpy.ndarray to Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am using XGBoost model for my data. I need to collect all the received values in a Dataframe.

x_train (pandas.core.frame.DataFrame) is 9 columns,

pred_prob (numpy.ndarray) is 5 columns,

y_test (numpy.ndarray) is 1 column,

pred (numpy.ndarray) is 1 column.

How can i do this?

When trying to build pred_prob, y_test, pred,

```
df = pd.DataFrame (np.concatenate (pred_prob, pred, y_test), axis = 0)
```

the following error occurs:

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Answer (score 1):

Give a tuple of ndarrays and axis=1 to np.concatenate (works only if ndarrays have same number of rows) :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((pred_prob, pred, y_test), axis=1))
```

Comment: My data [  …
[0.17250077 0.17303202 0.17306072 0.30882448 0.17258205]
[0.14553823 0.14860761 0.39314887 0.16709846 0.1456068 ]]
[2 3 4 1 1 1 3 3 2 4 1 2 4 0 3 4 2 2 3 1]
[2 3 4 1 1 1 3 3 4 4 1 2 4 0 3 4 4 2 3 1]

Comment: does not work even if I only use pred, y_test, again the same error

Comment: Have your tried my exact code and checked that all your matrices have same number of rows ?

Comment: pred_prob matrix 20 ,5

Comment: pred, y_test  - 20,

Comment: I was able to add to DataFrame x_test, pred, y_test

df = pd.DataFrame (x_test)
new_df = df.assign (Prediction = pred, Real = y_test)
prediction = pd.DataFrame (new_df)

but how else can I add the pred_ prob